# REDHAT8.2: libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: redhat, python

I have a problem where Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.2 (Ootpa) is failing to load,

`libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0` as follows

```
[root@sl2artemisapp04 1.0.0.1]# /opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/bin/gunicorn  --bind 0.0.0.0:8188 --workers=6 --worker-class sanic_gunicorn.Worker app_runner:app

Error: class uri 'sanic_gunicorn.Worker' invalid or not found:

[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 135, in load_class
    mod = import_module('.'.join(components))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic_gunicorn.py", line 15, in <module>
    from sanic import Sanic
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sanic.app import Sanic
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/app.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sanic.server import serve, serve_multiple, HttpProtocol, Signal
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sanic/server.py", line 19, in <module>
    from httptools import HttpRequestParser
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/httptools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .parser import *
  File "/opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/httptools/parser/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .parser import *
ImportError: libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
]
```

I have a different server where application is running with no issues,

```
[root@sl2artemisapp03 ~]# /opt/intuitive/dvmt-human-readable-api/1.0.0.1/bin/gunicorn  --bind 0.0.0.0:8188 --workers=6 --worker-class sanic_gunicorn.Worker app_runner:app
[2021-07-08 00:42:32 +0000] [438006] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
```

I have done find on both servers

```
[root@sl2artemisapp03 ~]# sudo find / -name libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0
/usr/lib64/libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0
```

where file exists
vs

```
[root@sl2artemisapp04 1.0.0.1]# sudo find / -name libpython3.6m.so.rh-python36-1.0
```

but here files does not exists at all, can someone let me know what redhat8.2 pkgs I need to install on bad server and how can I install it.

Vaibhav Chauhan

Comment: What did the software vendor say about this when you contacted them?

Comment: I did not contact software vendor.